# Mule with Spring batch integration

Tags: spring-batch

My requirement is I have to read the message from Queue using mule configuration and the message I have to pass to Spring batch for further processing. How do I pass the message to spring batch reader? Appreciate if somebody send me the code snippet if they have around this.

Thanks
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch provides a `JobLaunchingGateway` that can be used to launch Spring Batch jobs via messages.  Using this in combination with a `JobLaunchRequest` as the message body, you'd be able to launch your job with and pass job parameters that were in the message to the job components (readers, writers, etc).

You can read more about the `JobLaunchingGateway` here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html#launching-batch-jobs-through-messages

You can read more about the `JobLaunchRequest` here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/integration/launch/JobLaunchRequest.html

Comment: Thanks Michael. Which Spring batch version has these 2 classes? Do you have any sample program on this?

Comment: Spring Batch 3 has both of them.  Before Spring Batch 3, you could use the MessageChannelJobLauncher (the gateway wraps it) instead and wire it up yourself.  With examples, take a look at the integration test for the gateway here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-integration/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/integration/launch/JobLaunchingGatewayIntegrationTests.java

Comment: I'll try this. Just giving you more inputs about my issue and I hope your above input will solve that issue. My mule application is listening one queue and I received the xml message in String format in Mule listener. I have a job that reader is StaxEventItemReader which unmarshaller property is Jaxb2Marshaller object. I have to pass the xml String from Mule listener to the StaxEventItemReader to read the xml string and pass it to the writer object. I hope your above solution can solve this issue.

Comment: Hi Michael, I tried doing this that you have suggested. But how do I pass the xml string to the job reader that should read the xml message and process it further. Below is my job configuration <batch:job id="standingInstructionJob"> <batch:step id="uploadSI"> <batch:tasklet> <batch:chunk reader="xmlItemReader" writer="testInstructionWriter" commit-interval="1"> </batch:chunk> </batch:tasklet> </batch:step> </batch:job> I tried adding Jobparameter as a xml string but I am getting value too large for column "BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS"."STRING_VAL"

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question.  If you want to pass the actual message to the reader, you'll need to wrap the StaxEventItemReader in something that will read the message.  Spring Batch doesn't have a reader that will do that for you OOTB.

Comment: Is there any other good way to send the String message to the job reader? Can I do it using Spring batch integration? If yes please let me know if you have any example.

Comment: I think this looks like a generic requirement where I have a String or input stream that I have to pass to batch job reader to read it.

Comment: Had anyone implemented this?